# Error while running very long SQL query with UNION ALL operator in Vertica

Tags: sql, union, vertica

This is a sample of subquery used in Vertica Query which is a string generated from the application.

```
SELECT 1 as ID, 345.45 as PaidAmt FROM DUAL
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 as ID, 789.45 as PaidAmt FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
...
...
```

There are some cases when this subquery becomes huge as the number of rows with UNION ALL increases. Vertica supports this query to some extent. But when there is let's say 3000 + UNION ALL operator used in a subquery it throws an error.

> [SQL Error [4963] [54001]: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: The query
> contains a SET operation tree that is too complex to analyze

I could not find any documents that talk about the limited use of UNION ALL operator in query or length of the query string.

Is there any system parameter in Vertica or Linux for which we can change the value to successfully execute the query?

I have an alternate approach to fix the query removing UNION ALL. But looking for a solution to the error generated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: A better long term solution would be to maintain this data as an actual bona-fide table in your SQL database.  You may use Vertica's CSV loading tool (pretty sure that it has one).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yes, as one of the quick solutions we are creating a table to hold information and use that table in a query instead. Also, I have come up with an alternate query to remove the implementation of UNION ALL in this manner. The change will take time to implement in application. But wanted to know if there are any other alternatives to make query execution possible by changing some kind of variable parameters if there are any. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CSV option proves impossible, I would use a temporary table - and it would also speed up your query:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE helper_table(id,paidamt)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
          SELECT 1, 345.45 
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 789.45 
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 213.44
[.2997 more rows . .]
;

INSERT INTO helper_table
          SELECT 3001, 4345.45 
UNION ALL SELECT 3002, 3789.45 
UNION ALL SELECT 3003, 1213.44
[.2997 more rows . .]
;

SELECT
  <<whatever>>
FROM helper_table JOIN <<other_tables>> ON <<whatever>> 
;
```

The `helper_table` will die as soon as you log off again.

Alternatively, use vsql with a script like this:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE helper_table (
  id      INT
, paidamt NUMERIC(9,2)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

COPY helper_table FROM stdin;
   1|  345.45 
   2|  789.45 
   3|  213.44
3001| 4345.45 
3002| 3789.45 
3003| 1213.44
\.

-- Now you can work with it ...
SELECT * FROM helper_table;
```

Comment: Thanks! We are implementing a similar approach as a quick fix alternative to the query. But I want to know - Is there some sort of parameter in Vertica or Linux, which can fix the issue (execute the query as is) by changing its parameter value?

Comment: The answer to that is: no. Check this link: https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/LanguageElements/Expressions/Expressions.htm#4 . I would also argue that a table expression consisting of thousands of UNION SELECTs is a very inefficient use of resources in any SQL based database ....

Comment: thank you for the link. As it mentions - "The second limit is the number of recursions possible in an analytic expression. The limit is 2000. If this limit is exceeded then the error "The query contains an expression that is too complex to analyze" may be thrown. This limit cannot be increased."

Comment: @marcothesane So how will using a CREATE TABLE ... TEMPORARY... solve the problem? That will also have the same complex UNION based SQL and that will also fail, right? No?

Comment: No. You insert a block that is just not too big to run into the 2000 recursions limit of an analytic expression. Then you insert the next block. Then the next, until your tens of thousands of rows are in. You can even apply some physical design (ORDER BY, SEGMENTED BY ...) to support the subsequent join. And a LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE dies when you log off again.